# Join when match other wise use default value

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables a

```
C1  C2  Value
All All  5
da  All  6
```

and table b

```
C1  C2  
cc  a  
da  b
```

I want to get the match value for table b

```
C1  C2  Value
cc  a   5
da  b   6
```

I write a query like this

```
select b.*,a.* from a, b 
where 1=(case when a.C1=b.C1 then 1 
         when a.C1='All' then 1
         else 0)
and 1=(case when a.C2=b.C2 then 1 
         when a.C2='All' then 1
         else 0)
```

and got results

```
C1  C2  Value
cc  a   5
da  b   6    
da  b   5
```

How can I got the query to get the result as follow

```
C1  C2  Value
cc  a   5
da  b   6
```

Basically when there is a match using matching value, otherwise using the default value 'All', Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible for table A to have a row with "All" in C1 and a value like "b" in C2? If so, how would the results look in that case?

Comment: Your statement won't execute - you need an `END` for each `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your required output is not that clear to me, but maybe you need something like this:

```
select c1, c2 , value from
(
 select b.c1, b.c2, a.value,
 row_number() over ( partition by decode(a.c1, 'all', 0, 1) + decode(a.c2, 'all', 0, 1)
                     order by     decode(a.c1, 'all', 0, 1) + decode(a.c2, 'all', 0, 1) desc
                   ) as num
 from a join b
 on ( a.c1 = 'all' OR a.c1 = b.c1) and 
    ( a.c2 = 'all' OR a.c2 = b.c2)
)
where num = 1;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unusual join criteria. Left outer join with coalesce might be a simple way to get what you want, provided performance isn't a limitation.

```
select b.*, COALESCE(a1.Value, a2.Value, a3.Value, a4.Value)
from b LEFT OUTER JOIN a a1
ON a1.C1=b.C1 AND a1.C2=b.C2
LEFT OUTER JOIN a a2
ON a2.C1=b.C1 AND a2.C2='All'
LEFT OUTER JOIN a a3
ON a3.C1='All' AND a3.C2=b.C2
LEFT OUTER JOIN a a4
ON a4.C1='All' AND a4.C2='All'
```

Note that you will get multiple rows with this if there are:

- more than one a record containing All, All;
- more than one match for either column C1, C2 in a;

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a ( C1, C2, Value ) AS
SELECT 'All', 'All', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'da',  'All', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'da',  'b', 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b ( C1, C2 ) AS
SELECT 'cc', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'da', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'da', 'c' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT b.C1,
       b.C2,
       ( SELECT MAX ( value ) KEEP (
                    DENSE_RANK FIRST
                    ORDER BY 
                      CASE WHEN b.C1 = a.C1 AND b.C2 = a.C2 THEN 1
                           WHEN b.C1 = a.C1                 THEN 2
                           ELSE                                  3
                           END ASC
                  )
         FROM   table_a a
         WHERE  ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND b.C2 = a.C2  )
         OR     ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND a.C2 = 'All' )
         OR     ( a.C1 = 'All' AND a.C2 = 'All' )
       ) AS Value
FROM   table_b b;
```

**Results**:

```
C1 C2      VALUE
-- -- ----------
cc a           5 
da b           4 
da c           6
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT b.C1,
       b.C2,
       MAX ( value ) KEEP (
            DENSE_RANK FIRST
            ORDER BY 
              CASE WHEN b.C1 = a.C1 AND b.C2 = a.C2 THEN 1
                   WHEN b.C1 = a.C1                 THEN 2
                   ELSE                                  3
                   END ASC
       ) AS Value
FROM   table_b b
       INNER JOIN
       table_a a
ON         ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND b.C2 = a.C2  )
       OR  ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND a.C2 = 'All' )
       OR  ( a.C1 = 'All' AND a.C2 = 'All' )
GROUP BY b.C1, b.C2;
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT C1,
       C2,
       Value
FROM   (       
  SELECT b.C1,
         b.C2,
         value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY b.C1, b.C2
           ORDER BY  CASE WHEN b.C1 = a.C1 AND b.C2 = a.C2 THEN 1
                          WHEN b.C1 = a.C1                 THEN 2
                          ELSE                                  3
                          END ASC
         ) AS RN
  FROM   table_b b
         INNER JOIN
         table_a a
  ON         ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND b.C2 = a.C2  )
         OR  ( b.C1 = a.C1  AND a.C2 = 'All' )
         OR  ( a.C1 = 'All' AND a.C2 = 'All' )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

All should give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT b.C1,
           b.C2,
           max(value) value 
      FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON (DECODE (a.C2, 'All', b.C2,a.C2) = b.C2 AND DECODE (a.C1, 'All', b.C1,a.C1) = b.C1)
  GROUP BY b.C1,
           b.C2
```